# Algolia search error when "index.addObject()"

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I've installed algolia using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTXzxSlhTDM

I have firestore paid version and all was going okay till i created an item in my collection to try if it was working, but when i did it any item was added in my algolia index, so i went to cloud functions log and saw this:

```
addToIndex
TypeError: index.addObject is not a function
at exports.addToIndex.functions.firestore.document.onCreate.snapshot (/srv/index.js:15:22)
at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
at /worker/worker.js:825:24
at <anonymous>
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

I wasted 30 mins looking at the code, and rewriting it all perfectly exact as in the video, and searched for this error and didn't find anything, so here i'm

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

const APP_ID = functions.config().algolia.app;
const ADMIN_KEY = functions.config().algolia.key;

const client = algoliasearch(APP_ID, ADMIN_KEY);
const index = client.initIndex('items');

exports.addToIndex = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}')
    .onCreate(snapshot => {
        const data = snapshot.data();
        const objectID = snapshot.id;

        return index.addObject({ ...data, objectID });
    });
exports.updateIndex = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}')
    .onUpdate((change) => {
        const newData = change.after.data();
        const objectID = change.after.id;
        return index.saveObject({ ...newData, objectID });
    });
exports.deleteFromIndex = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}')
    .onDelete(snapshot => index.deleteObject(snapshot.id));
```

Comment: Which version of the Algolia client is used?

Comment: it should be the last, its full updated, how can i see it?

Comment: You can find the version of the package in the package.json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `addObject` method doesn't exist on the latest version. You have to use [`saveObject`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/add-objects/?language=javascript):

```
index.saveObject({ ...data, objectID })
```

Note that a tutorial for Algolia is available in Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).